# Change golang dependency c file compilation flags

Tags: c, go, compilation, compiler-flags

As I build a golang project it uses dependencies that come from c files. During build phase some warnings are printed like  `debugger.go:23:13: warning: unused function '_duk_debugger_attach' [-Wunused-function]`

Can I make this warnings into errors? I'm trying to add `CFLAGS=-Werror` into my makefile that compiles go project but the warnings still appear as warnings

Comment: Have you `export`-ed `CFLAGS`? Also, you can define such flags directly in the Go source files via the `#cgo` pseudo-directive.

Comment: I tried but dependencies somehow cannot see exported env (or maybe they re-define it?)